# Replace a broken img url with a default when the broken url does not exists with AngularJS jqlite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, broken-links

I want to replace all broken img url with a default when the broken url does not exists with AngularJS jqlite `attr()`. I use it like this but won't work.

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('AdminCtrl',function($scope{
    angular.element(document.querySelector('img')).attr("onerror","this.src='../assets/img/broken/broken-link.png'");
})
```

What is correct script?

Comment: to add ng if with img tag not enough for you?

Comment: @Erez No, some times `ng-src` has a link but that file on the server removed

Answer (score 1):

You have libraries that already do that.

Check [angular-fallback-src](https://github.com/tlvince/angular-fallback-src) and [angular-img-fallback](https://github.com/dcohenb/angular-img-fallback).

Comment: How to implement it without use directive?

Comment: You have to handle `onError` but it's an event, not an attribute. That's the mistake in your code.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/error/)

Answer (score 1):

there are few ways to solve that

try the next options

```
myApp.directive('onErrorSrc', function() {
     return {
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           element.bind('error', function() {
              if (attrs.src != attrs.onErrorSrc) {
                attrs.$set('src', attrs.onErrorSrc);
              }
           });
         }
     }
  });

<img ng-src="wrongUrl.png" on-error-src="someurl.png"/>
```

Or

```
<img ng-src="{{ imagesrc}}" onerror="this.src='someimgsrc.png'"/>
```

as you dont want to use directive you can use this img tag line will make the work for you

to do  it dynamicly

```
<img ng-src="{{ imagesrc}}" nerror="angular.element(this).scope().imgError()"/>
```

and implement this src on the function or scope var

check this plnkr
 https://plnkr.co/edit/S6KDo2crjMGASKtrToGo?p=preview

Comment: How to add `onerror` attribute dynamically to all `<img>` tag?

Comment: you should do onerror="angular.element(this).scope().imgError()"